# Python Web Proxy failing to load HTTPS sites

Tags: python, firefox, proxy

I'm writing a web proxy in Python. I have a problem where anytime I try to load a HTTPS website (in Firefox) I get a security warning error (I'll post a screenshot below). It would appear (from output of my program on the terminal) that my proxy is sending and receiving the data from the web server but Firefox is not loading it. I can load HTTP sites like example.com fine. I'm aware that I should be using threading for this but I wanted to build incrementally. Here's my code and some screen-grabs to better illustrate what's going on: Thanks a lot for you help!

```
import sys
import socket

# Constants
PORT = 9876
MAX_BUFFER = 4096
HOST = ''
BACKLOG = 5

def main():
    ''' This is the main function'''
# Start socket
    try:
        clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        clientSocket.bind((HOST, PORT))
        clientSocket.listen(BACKLOG)
        print 'Proxy running on %s:%d' % (HOST, PORT)

    except socket.error, (message):
        print message

        if clientSocket:
            clientSocket.close()

        sys.exit(1)

# Listen for requests
    while 1:
    # conn is the socket we can send and receive to/from the client
        print 'Listening to client'
        conn, client_addr = clientSocket.accept()
        request = conn.recv(MAX_BUFFER)

    # Parsing
        webserver, port = ParseHTTP(request)
    # Heard from client, now forward to server
        try:
            print 'Sending request to server'
            serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            serverSocket.connect((webserver, port))
            serverSocket.send(request)

            while 1:
                data = serverSocket.recv(MAX_BUFFER)

            # while there is data to receive from server
                if len(data) > 0:
                    conn.send(data)

                else:
                    print 'Completed sending data to client'
                    break

            serverSocket.close()
            conn.close()

        except socket.error, (message):
            print message

            if clientSocket:
                clientSocket.close()

            if conn:
                conn.close()

            if serverSocket:
                serverSocket.close()

            sys.exit(1)

    print 'Goodbye'
#******************End of main*********************

def ParseHTTP(request):
    first_line = request.split('\n')[0]
    print first_line
    url = first_line.split(' ')[1]
    http_pos = url.find('://')
    if http_pos == -1:
        temp = url
    else:
        temp = url[(http_pos + 3):]

    port_pos = temp.find(':')

    webserver_pos = temp.find('/')
    if webserver_pos == -1:
        webserver_pos = len(temp)
    webserver = ''
    port = -1

    if port_pos == -1 or webserver_pos < port_pos:
        port = 80
        webserver = temp[:webserver_pos]

    else:
        port = int((temp[(port_pos + 1):])[:webserver_pos - port_pos -1])
        webserver = temp[:port_pos]

    return webserver, port
#******************End of ParseWebServer()*********************

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: The security error message from Firefox]

[image: My proxy settings in Firefox, something wrong here?]

[image: You can see my proxy is fetching data from the webserver but Firefox throws that error screen]